# How to see relevence of a feature in any model in ScikitLearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I am using Logistic Regression and Linear SVC from scikit learn for categorisation of a document into 2 categories denoted by label 0 and label 1. I am using TFIDF Vectorizer for feature selection and I have extracted all the non-zero features from test document using transform function of TFIDF Vectorizer on it and now I want to know whether a particular feature is being used for label 1 or label 0.

Basically I want to know if my classifier is giving me answer as label 0, then based on what features it gave that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get_feature_names()` function to extract the feature names.You will get an array mapping for feature indices to feature names. You can read more about it [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.get_feature_names).

[This example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-topics-extraction-with-nmf-lda-py) explains how to print the feature names.

You can get the corresponding relevance values from [this link](https://buhrmann.github.io/tfidf-analysis.html). Skip to the section titled : **Making sense of the tf-idf matrix**. You will see that is makes use of `feature_names()` to extract the top values.

**EDIT** : Different classifiers have different ways to extract feature relevances. You can use [SelectFromModel in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#feature-selection-using-selectfrommodel) to extract the features based on the classifier selected. You can use it's [`get_support`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.get_support) function to get the feature indices. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_select_from_model_boston.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-select-from-model-boston-py) is example for the same.

Comment: Using that I can find out only the feature name but I want to know relevance of that feature used by classifier for generating the result.

Comment: Actually I have made use of coef_ attribute present in scikit classifiers to find out the relevence of feature for that classifier.

Comment: @ShubhamGarg coef_ does not imply the relevance of a feature. If you are using it as a measure of relevance, then it is wrong. See this answer here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202221/for-linear-classifiers-do-larger-coefficients-imply-more-important-features/202846 . The same applies for all other classifiers.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way to find relevance of features which are there in test set for that particular classifier ?

Comment: The classifier which is passed in SelectFromModel is already trained or it will be trained on features passed to it ?

Comment: @ShubhamGarg you can see in the example in this link : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_select_from_model_boston.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-select-from-model-boston-py   that it will be trained on the features passed to it.